# C# adding every table row to textbox from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, textbox

I've been working a bit with binding database tables to text boxes and I've encountered a problem. The code I have here gets all the columns I need from the table, but only 1 row's worth of data shows up. Is there a simple way to make every single row from the table appear in a text box? Or some other sort of text list?

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("SERVER=myserver;DATABASE=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader dr = null;

cmd.Connection = cn;
cn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DisasterID,DisasterType,Location,CurrentStatus,IntensityLevel,Latitude,Longitude FROM Disasters";
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read()) {
    txtFeeds.Text = dr["DisasterID"].ToString() + " " + dr["DisasterType"].ToString() + " " + dr["Location"].ToString() + " " + dr["CurrentStatus"].ToString() + " " + dr["IntensityLevel"].ToString() + " " + dr["Latitude"].ToString() + " " + dr["Longitude"].ToString();
}
cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `while` loop and append each line to textbox by `txtFeeds.Text +=`

```
while(dr.Read()) {
    txtFeeds.Text += dr["DisasterID"].ToString() + " " 
   + dr["DisasterType"].ToString() + " " 
   + dr["Location"].ToString() + " " 
   + dr["CurrentStatus"].ToString() + " " 
   + dr["IntensityLevel"].ToString() + " " 
   + dr["Latitude"].ToString() + " " + dr["Longitude"].ToString();
}
```

If you need more performance you can use [**`StringBuilder`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to append text and finally set textbox text using [**`StringBuilder.ToString`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1063zt.aspx) method.

**Edit.**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (dr.Read())
{
    sb.AppendLine(dr["DisasterID"].ToString() + " " 
    + dr["DisasterType"].ToString() + " " 
    + dr["Location"].ToString() + " " 
    + dr["CurrentStatus"].ToString() + " " 
    + dr["IntensityLevel"].ToString() + " " 
    + dr["Latitude"].ToString() + " " + dr["Longitude"].ToString());
}

txtFeeds.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: That works great, but could you also show me how to start a new line after every row/entry? Thanks

Comment: @NickV added sample code, `StringBuilder.AppendLine` will add each recode as new line

Answer (score 1):

First of all its a bad idea trying display records from a table in a single textbox. 
If you still want to do it,

Use a while loop instead of IF condition

```
 while(dr.Read()) 
{

}
```

Use a string builder and append all your  column values to it and after while loop exists use the values in the string builder and set it to the field.

```
StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

while(dr.Read()) {
            values.Append( dr["DisasterID"].ToString() + " " + dr["DisasterType"].ToString() + " " + dr["Location"].ToString() + " " + dr["CurrentStatus"].ToString() + " " + dr["IntensityLevel"].ToString() + " " + dr["Latitude"].ToString() + " " + dr["Longitude"].ToString());
        }

 txtFeeds.Text = values.ToString();
```